# Scroll the content within my subnavbar

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

HTML Code

```
<div id="subnavigation">
    <?php
    $verbindung = mysql_connect("host", "user" , "pw") 
    or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden"); 

    mysql_select_db("db") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");

    $sub_instr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM instrument ORDER BY InstrName");

    while($sub = mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_instr))
    {?>
    <div class="sub-item" data-target="<? echo $sub["InstrID"] ?>">
        <a href="#" data-target="<? echo $sub["InstrID"] ?>"><? echo $sub["InstrName"] ?></a>
    </div><?
    }?>
</div>
```

jQuery Code (with some additional code for other subnavigations)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form#email_formular').hide();
$('p#sign_formular').hide();
$('.content-item#orga').hide();
$('.content-item#feedback').hide();

$('.sub-item a, .sub-item').click(function(){

    var buttonID = $(this).data('target');

    $('table.hidden').hide();
    $('table#' + buttonID).show();

    $('form#email_formular').hide();        
    $('p#sign_formular').hide();

    $('form#' + buttonID).show();
    $('p#' + buttonID).show();

    $('.content-item#overview').hide();
    $('.content-item#orga').hide();
    $('.content-item#feedback').hide();
    $('.content-item#' + buttonID).show();

});

});
```

I didn't post the css file, because I don't think it is neccessary. (If you still need it, just tell me)

Problem:

The subnav gets it's content out of a SQL database. In this example, there are more than 10 entries. This is way too long for my page design, so I would like to limit the shown content to 4-5 entries and make the rest available by hovering over the subnavigation and give the user the possibility to scroll down/up with two small arrows at the top and bottom of the div.

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so please keep that in mind, when you show me something to solve the problem. :)

Comment: Thx! I'll try to keep that in mind, even if it is this early/ late ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to have two `<div>` containers - one for shown content, the other for hidden. Add a loop counter variable to your while loop and detect it as such:

```
<div class="shown_content">
<?php
$loopcount   = 0;
$shown_limit = 5;

while(){ // your db loop
    if($loopcount == $shown_limit){
        ?></div><div class="hidden_content"><?php
    }

    // output the row

    $loopcount++;
}
?>
</div>
```

And in CSS, specify

```
.hidden_content{
    display: none;
}
```

And show `.hidden_content` with Javascript when the user hovers or clicks the relevant part of the UI.

**Edit:** I just realized I didn't answer the part about hovering and scrolling up and down. For the hovering part, just add a [hover listener](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) (jQuery: `$('#shown_content').hover(function(){ showAllContent(); });` or something).

For the up/down buttons, you can either let the user scroll naturally inside the `<div>` that contains both `.shown_content` and `.hidden_content`, or add buttons and use jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to manipulate the scroll position inside said containing div.

Comment: The php part helped a lot. Thanks. For the jQuery Part I still need plenty of help, but I'll try to write some code first.